# Send file from Android Wear to phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to build into my app the code needed to send a text file in CSV format from an android wear watch to its paired phone, but I want to do it so the phone receives the file without the intervention of an application on the phone side. So it is the Android OS on the phone side which takes the incomming file, like if it was a file downloaded from the internet for instance, this way any app installed on the phone side can take over and open the sent CSVfile.

I have researched over the documentation and also internet and the only thing I found is examples of how to send files where we have our code in both the smatwatch and also the phone devices:
[Send file Google Wear to mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808283/send-file-google-wear-to-mobile)

I have experimented with the recommended code in Google but so far no luck.

Thanks,
Diego.

Comment: Some of your requirements seems not possible. You can't deploy an Android-based wear app without having an app on the handheld too.

Comment: Yes, that is correct although I have seen some post from people who avoided it. Not relevant anyway, I still would have the desire to let the OS receive the file as opposed to the phone app. Although the strategy at this point is moving towards sending the file from the watch the phone and then sharing the file from the phone app once it takes control and let the intents manage it.